# How to get active orders for past year

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table which has start and end date. Based on that table, I have to get the active orders for the past 12 months.

In end date NULL means it is active order until now.

Table Basic idea

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Based on the past experience I'm able to write the query like this for the current year January but i need it for all the months as shown in the above picture

```
select
      mnth.num, count(*)
from (
    select 1 AS num union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all 
    select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select 11 union all select 12
    ) mnth
left join (    
      select
            o.id
          , case 
               when o.start_date < date_format(current_date(), '%Y-01-01') then 1
               else month(o.start_date)
               end AS start_month
          , case 
               when o.end_date < date_format(current_date(), '%Y-01-01') then 0
               when o.end_date >= date_format(current_date(), '%Y-01-01') then month(o.end_date)
               else month(current_date())
               end AS end_month
      from order o
      ) active_work_orders on mnth.num between active_work_orders.start_month and active_work_orders.end_month  
where mnth.num <= month(current_date())
group by
      mnth.num
;
```

Based on the output I have to generate a graph. Kindly help on this

Fiddle link [click here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=b24018efb9cde45b688068f9ccb701fd)

Comment: Is your expected output correct? for example 1285,1286 and 1287 seem to be the only ones active in feb17 and mar17

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes it is correct, because null in the end date means it is active only. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am confused 1289 is considered active in feb17 even though the start date is april?

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for pointing it out. It is misleading so updated all the start dates to 2016

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle with some improvement from the @P.Salmon answer http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c5105cd887752e3abc3d5ee55f0ec039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
select mthnum,
        count(*) 
from
(
select mthnum, o.*,year(start_date)* 12 + month(start_date),year(end_date) * 12 + month(end_date)
from
(
    #select 2016*12 + 11 AS mthnum union all select 2016*12 + 12 union all select 2017*12 + 1 union all select 2017*12 + 2
    select 2017*100 + 2 as mthnum
     union all select 2017*100 + 3 union all select 2017*100 + 4 union all select 2017*100 + 5 union all select 2017*100 + 6
     union all select 2017*100 + 7 union all select 2017*100 + 8 union all select 2017*100 + 9 union all select 2017*100 + 10
     union all select 2017*100 + 11 union all select 2017*100 + 12 union all select 2018*100 + 1
) mth
cross join
(select * from order_test_new #where order_num = 1288
) o
) s where (s.mthnum >= year(s.start_date)*100  + month(start_date))  and 
    (end_date is null or s.mthnum <= year(end_date) * 100 + month(s.end_date))
group by mthnum
```

result

```
+--------+----------+
| mthnum | count(*) |
+--------+----------+
| 201702 |        9 |
| 201703 |        9 |
| 201704 |        9 |
| 201705 |        8 |
| 201706 |        8 |
| 201707 |        8 |
| 201708 |        8 |
| 201709 |        7 |
| 201710 |        7 |
| 201711 |        6 |
| 201712 |        6 |
| 201801 |        6 |
+--------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This considers that an order with and end_date is active in the end_date month.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I am trying to understand the query. I have never familiar with this kind of query before.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the help of [`extract` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) to extract year and month and do a `group by` based on that.

Then, for displaying, you can use [`date_format` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

So, here it goes:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%b-%y') AS `Month`, COUNT(*) AS `Active`
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    end_date IS NULL
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM start_date)
```

For getting result from last 12 months only, you can use the following:

```
SELECT 
    `month_list`.`month`, IFNULL(`active_orders`.`active_count`, 0) AS `active_count`
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%b-%y') AS `month` 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 8 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 9 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MONTH, '%b-%y') 
            UNION 
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH, '%b-%y')) 
    AS `months`) as `month_list`
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%b-%y') AS `month`, COUNT(*) AS `active_count`
    FROM
        `order`
    WHERE
        end_date IS NULL
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM start_date)) as `active_orders` on `month_list`.`month` = `active_orders`.`month`;
```

Comment: With the given solution I am getting output like this http://rextester.com/XLLIAM95959 can you please check on it

Comment: The null test is inappropriate for example order 1288 was active april - september but the null test excludes it from the result set.

Comment: @jomoos It's a bit more complicated than that did, you check against the ops required result?

Comment: @jomoos Based on the given query results appear to be incorrect, because in August 2017 active orders are 8 but in result it shows only 1, that means it showed completed order in August 2017.

Comment: @vvr02 Updated the answer

Comment: @Jomoos thanks a lot for the help but still not getting the correct results http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=729f633ba474aa441d887fd766c8c52b

Comment: @Jomoos maybe my question was misleading updated the question also please have a look